# What is meaning of separate 'bias' weights stored in Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

**Post-edit:** Turns out I got confused while constantly playing with the three functions below.

```
model.weights
model.get_weights()
model.layer(i).get_weights()
```

1. `model.layer(i).get_weights()` returns **two** separate arrays (without any tags) which are `kernel` and `bias` if *bias* exists in the model.
2. `model.get_weights()` directly returns all the weights without any tags.
3. `model.weights` returns weights and a bit of info such as `name` of the layer it belongs to and its `shape`. I was using this one for the experiment in the question.

What confused me was simply 1 and 3 above.

*Note:* I've decided not to delete the question because it received an answer and with the post-edit may it still help someone.

---

*The question was...*

After saving a Keras model, when I check the weights, I notice 2 separate *bias*es.

Below is a part of weights listed by names.

```
conv2d/kernel:0
conv2d/bias:0
```

`kernel` ones store a *bias* array as their 2nd *numpy* array element which I knew as the original *bias* of the layer. Then, there is `bias` ones as well separately.

Which one serves what purpose? What is the difference between them?

Comment: There are no two biases, the kernel does not have a bias, and you are showing two different layers, that is why there are two biases. Not sure what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convolution layer (conv2d) has a kernel and a bias term and the dense layer (dense) has also a kernel and a bias term. The bias terms are here to give a new degree of freedom for each layer making the neural net more powerful to predict.